# Initialize viewHolder in Fragment

Tags: android

I want to add editing tasks through dialogs in my app. The thing is I can't initialize viewHolder to access the bindingAdapterPosition. I need it to pass the data and update the viewModel. Tried adding it in the constructor - didn't work. I know I have to initialize the viewHolder, but don't know how.

RecyclerviewFragment.kt:

```
class RecyclerviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel
    private lateinit var viewHolder: ViewHolder
    private lateinit var adapter: ListAdapter

    private var _binding: FragmentRecyclerviewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

        adapter = ListAdapter{showUpdateDialog()}
        val adapter = ListAdapter{showUpdateDialog()}
        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // Creates a controller responsible for swiping and moving the views in recyclerview
        val itemTouchController = ItemTouchHelper(
            object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: ViewHolder, target: ViewHolder,
                ): Boolean {
                    // Move specific item from "fromPos" to "toPos" in recyclerview adapter
                    val fromPos = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
                    val toPos = target.bindingAdapterPosition
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos)
                    return true // true if moved, false otherwise

                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    mUserViewModel.deleteUser(adapter.getTaskPosition(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition))
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Task deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
            })

        itemTouchController.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)

        mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun updateItemInDatabase(dialog: DialogInterface) {
        val editText = (dialog as AlertDialog).findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
        val task = editText?.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(task)) {
            // Update an entity
            mUserViewModel.updateUser(adapter.getTaskPosition(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Task updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill out required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun inputCheck(task: String): Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(task))
    }

    private fun showUpdateDialog() {
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setView(R.layout.fragment_add)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to negative button press
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.cancelled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialogInterface, _ ->
                    // Respond to positive button press
                    updateItemInDatabase(dialogInterface)
                }
                .show()
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
class RecyclerviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: ListAdapter

    private var _binding: FragmentRecyclerviewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

        adapter = ListAdapter{ user ->  showUpdateDialog(user)}
        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // Creates a controller responsible for swiping and moving the views in recyclerview
        val itemTouchController = ItemTouchHelper(
            object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: ViewHolder, target: ViewHolder,
                ): Boolean {
                    // Move specific item from "fromPos" to "toPos" in recyclerview adapter
                    val fromPos = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
                    val toPos = target.bindingAdapterPosition
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos)
                    return true // true if moved, false otherwise

                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    mUserViewModel.deleteUser(adapter.getTaskPosition(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition))
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Task deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
            })

        itemTouchController.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)

        mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun updateItemInDatabase(user: User) {
        val editText = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
        val task = editText?.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(task)) {
            // Update an entity
            mUserViewModel.updateUser(user)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Task updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill out required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun inputCheck(task: String): Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(task))
    }

    private fun showUpdateDialog(user: User) {
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setView(R.layout.fragment_add)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to negative button press
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.cancelled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to positive button press
                    val taskText = view
                        ?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
                        ?.text?.toString()
                    updateItemInDatabase(user)
                }
                .show()
    }
}
```

The app doesn't crash when you press ok in the updateDialog anymore, but it doesn't really update the database or the recyclerview items. The cause is that I can't figure out how to update it as I made the list adapter return the whole user(id, task) and don't know how to update only the task. Adding some adapter code to let it explain it by itself.

```
class ListAdapter(var imageListener:(user: User)->Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
...
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = dataSet[position]
        holder.taskTitle.text = currentItem.task

        holder.editImage.setOnClickListener {
            imageListener(getTaskPosition(position))
        }

        holder.notificationImage.setOnClickListener {
            val action = RecyclerviewFragmentDirections.actionRecyclerFragmentToNotificationFragment()
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

    fun getTaskPosition(position: Int): User {
        return dataSet[position]
    }
```

I get the idea and seem to understand the problem more. Now I see that I didn't use the whole potential of passing the data from adapter, but there is still an issue, if you could guide me through it I would be honored :))

Edit 2:

```
class RecyclerviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mUserViewModel: UserViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: ListAdapter

    private var _binding: FragmentRecyclerviewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[UserViewModel::class.java]

        adapter = ListAdapter{ user ->  showUpdateDialog(user)}
        val recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // Creates a controller responsible for swiping and moving the views in recyclerview
        val itemTouchController = ItemTouchHelper(
            object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
            ) {
                override fun onMove(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    viewHolder: ViewHolder, target: ViewHolder,
                ): Boolean {
                    // Move specific item from "fromPos" to "toPos" in recyclerview adapter
                    val fromPos = viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition
                    val toPos = target.bindingAdapterPosition
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos)
                    return true // true if moved, false otherwise

                }

                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    mUserViewModel.deleteUser(adapter.getTaskPosition(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition))
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Task deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.bindingAdapterPosition)
                }
            })

        itemTouchController.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerView)

        mUserViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun updateItemInDatabase(user: User) {
        val editText = view?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
        val task = editText?.text.toString()

        if(inputCheck(task)) {
            // Update an entity
            mUserViewModel.updateUser(user)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Task updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill out required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun inputCheck(task: String): Boolean {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(task))
    }

    private fun showUpdateDialog(user: User) {
            MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
                .setView(R.layout.fragment_add)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to negative button press
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.cancelled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { _, _ ->
                    // Respond to positive button press
                    val taskText = view
                        ?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
                        ?.text?.toString()
                    updateItemInDatabase(User(user.id, taskText.toString()))
                }
                .show()
    }
}
```

With this code it seems like the function is working, however, it can't access the taskText value? If I try to edit any of the tasks in the emulator it updates to "null" Providing the ViewModel, but I don't think there is an issue there. It is probably rooted somewhere in the value itself.

UserViewModel.kt:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<User>>
    private val repository: UserRepository

    init {
        val userDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(application).userDao()
        repository = UserRepository(userDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun updateUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updateUser(user)
        }
    }

    fun deleteUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteUser(user)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ViewHolder` is an internal thing your `Adapter` deals with - the `Fragment` shouldn't be interacting directly with them at all. Your `Adapter` should be passing *events* to a listener, like *delete this item* or whatever. If your `Fragment` handles those events, it can show a confirmation dialog, and then call a `deleteItem(item)` method on the `ViewModel`. Think of it like the event flowing *Adapter -> Fragment -> VM -> repository* etc, you shouldn't need to "go back" and ask the *Adapter* which item it's looking at again

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. The deleting method works perfectly, however, if I try to press the "ok" button in the editing dialog everything crashes, cause the viewHolder isn't initialized.

Comment: Why does your `updateItemInDatabase` function need access to a `ViewHolder` at all? It's not initialised because it's a local variable inside a `Fragment`, and you haven't set it to anything. But you *shouldn't be doing that anyway* because the Fragment shouldn't be poking around in the Adapter's internals like that. If you're going to keep a reference to anything, just store the thing you want from the Adapter in the first place - in this case, the result of `getTaskPosition`. Pass that out (from the Adapter) when the user clicks delete or whatever, and use that when the dialog is confirmed

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick sketch so you see what I'm talking about:

```
// your adapter already takes a callback function - make it send some data
// about the item being clicked. I'm assuming it's an ID here but you could
// pass back a specific object too
class ListAdapter(
    private val onDeleteListener: (itemId: Int) -> Unit
) ...
```

In the `Fragment`

```
// onCreate
adapter = ListAdapter { itemId -> showUpdateDialog(itemId) }

// dialog function should take the ID as a parameter
private fun showUpdateDialog(itemId: Int) {
    ...
    .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok)) { dialogInterface, _ ->
        // Don't send the dialog interface - pass the actual data you want to use
        val taskText = (dialogInterface as AlertDialog)
            .findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDialog)
            ?.text?.toString()
        updateItemInDatabase(itemId, taskText)
    }
...
}


// Your update function acts on specific data - it has no knowledge of how the rest
// of the app is implemented, it's not hardwired into other components etc
private fun updateItemInDatabase(itemId: Int, task: String?) {
    if(inputCheck(task)) {
        mUserViewModel.updateUser(itemId)
    }
}
```

See how much simpler that is? You have a clear direction of data flow, where the Adapter hands a specific piece of data to its callback function, which passes it to the confirmation dialog, which passes it to the update function which needs that specific piece of data. The only involvement the `Adapter` has is saying "hey, an item was clicked, here's the info". You don't need to go asking for more details later, like "so hey what are you currently displaying" - that was passed as part of the event's data.

---

That's cleaner in general, but *especially* with `RecyclerView`s you don't want to be poking at their internals, keeping references to `ViewHolder`s etc, because that state is volatile. The way they work is by reusing those objects to display different data, so keeping long-running references to them assuming they're displaying a particular item is asking for trouble. It *probably* doesn't matter so much here (if you tap an item to get a dialog the user probably can't get it to scroll to another position) but it's better to not do that thing at all.

---

also btw, this is a bug:

```
// top-level variable
adapter = ListAdapter{showUpdateDialog()}
// local variable
val adapter = ListAdapter{showUpdateDialog()}
// local variable
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

You're creating two separate instances of your `ListAdapter` - one is stored long-term, the other is the one you actually set on your `RecyclerView`. The long-term one is what you're accessing in `updateItemInDatabase`, the one that's not actually being used by a `RecyclerView`, so it's not the thing that was actually being clicked (and it won't have any `ViewHolder`s yet either). This is why it's better to just pass data in one direction if you can, less chance of complications being introduced!

Comment: Could you please look at my edit? Think we are getting somewhere :))

Comment: @Fog *it doesn't really update the database or the recyclerview items* - that depends on what you're doing in `mUserViewModel.updateUser`. You're already observing `mUserViewModel.readAllData` and calling `adapter.setData` when that value changes, so your `RecyclerView` will update when you set a new value on that `LiveData` (so long as `setData` also refreshes with `notifyDatasetChanged` or something). So your ViewModel needs to update `readAllData` - either directly (setting its `value`) or by having it expose a `LiveData` returned by a DB query, which updates when you update the DB

Comment: What do you think about it now? Can you think of any direction I could go in?